# It overwrites automatically in the UI what I change in the dialog Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

When i open the dialog all things are changeable jut the budget not, they change after I save, but the budget is automatically shown in the UI, what I want is after I click save the budget should change not automatically overwriting.
The budget is calling from code at ngOnInit.

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public editPosition) {
 }
 ngOnInit() {

this.store.select('BudconItem').subscribe(state => {
  this.editBudget = state.budgets.get(this.editPosition.budgetIds[0]);
});
}
save() {
 this.store.dispatch(new UpsertPositionAction(this.editPosition));
this.store.dispatch(new UpsertBudgetAction(this.editBudget));
}
```

This is the template of Dialog.

```
 <app-input-field orientation="top" labelWidth="85px;" label="Planned 
 Budget:">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="editBudget.planned" 
  style="width: 100%;">
      </app-input-field>
```

Comment: Sorry but your question/issue isn't very clear. What are "all things" that are "changeable"? How is the "budget" not changeable? What are the errors you get when you save? What is "the backend Angular 4"?

Comment: @bygrace now it is working I can store everything but this.editBudger is automatically changing in template the budget how it is possible to not pass the original reference but to make Object.assing and than if I save the new budget that was entered to dialog after i save this change not automatically to shown in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time, but I fixed the problem.

Instead of

```
this.store.select('BudconItem').subscribe(state => {
this.editBudget = state.budgets.get(this.editPosition.budgetIds[0]);
});
}
```

I made

```
  this.store.select('BudconItem').subscribe(state => {
  this.editBudget = Object.assign({}, 
  state.budgets.get(this.editPosition.budgetIds[0]));
   });
  }
```